# Why is my producer consumer deadlocking (or livelocking)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to implement a typical producer consumer using reentrant locks.
Producer thread prints even numbers and consumer threads print odd numbers.
Here is my Code, But for some reason it is deadlocking
The runnable tasks

```
public class EvenPrinterRunnable  implements Runnable {
    SharedBuffer buf;
    public EvenPrinterRunnable(SharedBuffer buf) {
        this.buf = buf;

        Thread.currentThread().setName("Even Runnable");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buf.printEven();
        }

    }
}

public class OddPrinterRunnable implements Runnable {
    SharedBuffer buf;
    public OddPrinterRunnable(SharedBuffer buf){
        this.buf = buf;
        Thread.currentThread().setName("ODD Runnable");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            buf.printOdd();
        }
    }
}
```

The shared Buffer

```
public class SharedBuffer {
    Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

    Condition evenNotPrinted = lock.newCondition();
    Condition oddNotPrinted  = lock.newCondition();

    int currentNumber = 0;

    public void printEven() {
        System.out.println("from even");
        try {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                oddNotPrinted.await();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(" being printed by thread " + "" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "+ currentNumber);
            currentNumber++;
            evenNotPrinted.signalAll();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void printOdd() {
        System.out.println("from odd");
        try {
            lock.lock();
            try {
                evenNotPrinted.await();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println(" being printed by thread " + "" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " "+ currentNumber);
            currentNumber++;
            oddNotPrinted.signalAll();
        }
        finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

The driver class

```
public class OddEvenDriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //using runnables with lock buffer

        SharedBuffer buf1 = new SharedBuffer();
        EvenPrinterRunnable epr = new EvenPrinterRunnable(buf1);
        OddPrinterRunnable opr = new OddPrinterRunnable(buf1);

        ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        es.submit(opr);
        es.submit(epr);
        es.shutdown();
    }
}
```

It is outputting

```
from even
from odd
```

Or

```
from odd
from even
```

That means each thread is acquiring the lock and then it waits on a condition evenNotPrinted and oddNotPrinted, and since no one of them can progress until the signal is called, So my question is , shall I signal each condition at the start of the method itself?
What am i missing here

Comment: Is it possible that `await()` is reached after `signal()` has been called?

Comment: It seems reasonably clear: each of the threads is trying to acquire a lock, and then waiting for a signal that the other will send *after* it has acquired the lock and received the signal. The first thread acquires the lock, and then waits for that signal; the second thread can't acquire the lock. So it's deadlock.

Comment: Yes thanks everyone , I understood that is the issue, But I have seen this idiom being used very frequently. I was wondering what was i missing.

Comment: @AndyTurner  Got it working by taking one more boolean flag and  await(ing) in while loops on this boolean.  Is it overkill , or is there any elegant way

Comment: I don't get why you call this "producer consumer."  That name usually applies to a pattern where there's a blocking queue, and one or more "producer" threads that put things into the queue, and one or more "consumer" threads that take things out of the queue.

Comment: @jameslarge Not to be taken literally, you are right :-). I meant the problem is similar in terms of synchronization  requirements , which we usually 
 tackle in producer-consumer.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is , shall I signal each condition at the start of the method itself?

No.  That won't work.  A condition variable does not remember that it previously was signalled when a thread calls `condition.await()`.  The `condition.signal()` and `condition.signalAll()` functions do not do anything at all unless some other thread already is waiting for the signal.

Condition variables are a low-level synchronization mechanism that is intended to be used in a very specific way to implement queues and semaphores and other higher-level synchronized objects.  The [Guarded Blocks tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html) explains it in detail.  (Note: the tutorial talks about `object.wait()` and `object.notify()` and `synchronized` blocks, but the concepts all maps directly onto `Lock` and `Condition` objects.)

Your basic problem is that your two threads can't be completely symmetrical with one another.  One of them has to go *first*.  Your main() thread must either wake one of them up, or construct one with an argument that says, "you first."